# Unable to change brightness on Sony EH18FA

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, brightness, vaio, sony

I couldn't change brightness of my Sony EH18FA laptop with Ubuntu 13.04. My laptop has Nvidia Geforce 410M GPU.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 along with Windows 7 Home Basic.

The brightness can't be changed using (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd>) keys nor from system sittings, although the slider changed but the brightness of screen not changed.

I tried a lot of recommended solutions but no one of them worked. I am afraid that I need install some drivers or something like that.

Comment: Can you try to change the brightness with [Brightness Controller](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness)?

Comment: yeah, it works thank you very much :) but only through this app. So I can't change the brightness using the hotkeys as fn+f5 nor from the system settings. Is there another way to solve the problem ? and thank you again for your help :)

Comment: I think that only way now is with using this controller or using `xrandr` in command line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Ubuntu brightness controler's bug.

You can use [alternative Brightness Controller](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness) or `xrandr` in command line.